# PrimeFaces 5.1 filterFunction - is it possible to get the whole line from the table?

Tags: java, primefaces, datatable

I'm filtering my dataTable and want to filter it with custom function. The problem is, that I want to take as input two columns of datatable. Default signature for implementing filterFunction is `public boolean filter(Object value, Object filter, Locale locale)` and in `value` parameter it holds contents of whatever is passed by `"filterBy"` attribute. What's making it's more tricky - that the field I filter with is not the key - it can have same values. Is it possible to pass more than one value to `"filterBy"` or somehow get the whole dataTable line in filter function in backing bean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to solve it: whatever is passed to `"filterBy"` attribute is in EL(Expression Language), so I can write my filter like this:

in xhtml: 
`... filterBy="#{item.property1};#{item.property2}" ...`

and in filter function:

```
public boolean filter(Object value, Object filter, Locale locale){
...
String[] properties = value.toString().split(";");
...
```